# Convert a Hashtable to a string of key value pairs

Tags: powershell

I have a hashtable of file extensions with counts

like so:

```
$FileExtensions = @{".foo"=4;".bar"=5}

Function HashConvertTo-String($ht) {
 foreach($pair in $ht.GetEnumerator()) {
 $output+=$pair.key + "=" + $pair.Value + ";"
 }

 $output
}


$hashString = HashConvertTo-String($FileExtensions)

$hashString.TrimEnd(';') -eq ".foo=4;.bar=5"
```

The last line should return $true

This works but looking for a more elegant way (removing trailing ; is optional)

I guess what I'm really looking for is a -join for hashtables or something similar

Thoughts???

Answer (score 40, accepted):

PowerShell won't automatically enumerate a hashtable, so you're forced to call `GetEnumerator()` or the `Keys` property.  After that, there are a few options.  First, using `$OFS` Ouptut Field Seperator. This string is used when an array is converted to a string.  By default, this is `""` but you can change it:

```
$FileExtensions = @{".foo"=4;".bar"=5}
$OFS =';'
[string]($FileExtensions.GetEnumerator() | % { "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)" })
```

Next using the -join operator:

```
$FileExtensions = @{".foo"=4;".bar"=5}
($FileExtensions.GetEnumerator() | % { "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)" }) -join ';'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but this code should work:

```
Function HashConvertTo-String($ht) { 
  $first = $true
  foreach($pair in $ht.GetEnumerator()) { 
    if ($first) 
    {
       $first = $false
    } 
    else 
    {
       $output += ';'
    }
    $output+="{0}={1}" -f $($pair.key),$($pair.Value)
   } 
   $output
  }
```